# Integration of Webpack to PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, webpack, phpstorm

I am trying to integrate Webpack to PhpStorm (to my Symfony 4 application).

Everything works fine (building JS and CSS files, ...) but the IDE doesn't suggest when I am including built files in twig template using asset function:

[image: as you can see here]

I have this in my `config/packages/framework.yaml`

```
framework:
   assets:
    json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

And this in `package.json`

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.17.0"
 },
```

Is there anything more I need to set to make this work?

Comment: do you have `build` directory marked as excluded?

Comment: No, it is not market as axcluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. You have to config Symfony plugin for PhpStorm to use Symfony 4 directory hierarchy (`web` was renamed to `public`, ...). This [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkJIR.png) can be found in `File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Symfony`.